# Android parsing JSON - help needed

Tags: android, json

I'm trying to parse this json data:

```
{
  "KEY_ONE_TEST": {
    "0": {
      "Destination": [
        "The Future"
      ],
      "Id": [
        "2"
      ]
    },
    "1": {
      "Destination": [
        "Milky way"
      ],
      "Id": [
        "2"
      ],
      "VehicleType": "T"
    }
  }
}
```

And can't, for the life of me, work out how to do it. I guess its one json object with a variable called KEY_ONE_TEST that is a json array.

I can read the "top level" stuff with:

```
JSONObject stop = new JSONObject(strData);
while(stop.keys().hasNext()) {
  String id = stop.keys().next(); // gives KEY_ONE_TEST
```

But I cant work out how to get the the array out from the id.

Anyone help?

ADDED COMMENT: I'm trying to do generically as well, so I can't use hard coded names like  'KEY_ONE_TEST'/ '0' '1' etc.

TIA.

Comment: It looks like KEY_ONE_TEST is an object with properties 0, 1,... and property 0 has destination(array), id(array).. are you trying to read the entire JSON object or just the array, which is destination and Id?

Comment: Do you know what arrays are? Seems strange that you use `"0"` and `"1"` as object keys instead of an array and arrays (`[ "2" ]`) as identifiers (`"Id"`).

Answer (score 0):

You can get to the Id the following way:

```
JSONObject stop = new JSONObject(strData);
JSONObject keyOneTest = stop.getJSONObject("KEY_ONE_TEST");
JSONObject zeroKey = keyOneTest.getJSONObject("0");
JSONArray idZeroKey = zeroKey.getJSONArray("Id");
```

Comment: sorry should have made it clear, i can't use hard coded names/values either I won't know what the actual value in KEY_ONE_TEST will be.

Comment: You should probably think about the design of your JSON data if it's in your hand.

Comment: @push22 you still need help with this?

Answer (score 0):

it depends of your JSON structure,  for example the code below permits to navigate and to get keys and values using your structure:

```
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject("your JSON");

    JSONObject jsonObjectMain = jsonObject.getJSONObject("KEY_ONE_TEST");
    System.out.println("jsonObjectMain >> " + jsonObjectMain.toString());

    Iterator<String> itMain = jsonObjectMain.keys();

    while (itMain.hasNext()) {
        String keyMain = itMain.next();
        System.out.println("itMain.key >> " + keyMain);

        JSONObject jsonObjectSecond = jsonObjectMain.getJSONObject(keyMain);
        Iterator<String> itSecond = jsonObjectSecond.keys();
        while (itSecond.hasNext()) {
            String keySecond = itSecond.next();
            System.out.println("itSecond.key >> " + keySecond);
            System.out.println("itSecond.value >> " + jsonObjectSecond.get(keySecond));

        }

    }
```

try it!

Answer (score 0):

got the backend dev to produce more a meaning-full data representation. i now don't have to screw around objects and key iteration, i can now just use arrays to walk the key data.